# Sitecore Active Directory Module: GetUsers() not returning all user records

Tags: active-directory-module

Sitecore 8.1 here, I'm currently using the Sitecore **AD Module 1.3**.

When I search through my users from the back-end using the User Manager, I can easily find all the users I want.

When I try to retrieve the from my code though, using `UserManager.GetUsers()`, some users - seemingly at random - don't show up at all.

**Question**:

Why is this happening?

Is there a configuration field I'm not aware of that makes so that they don't show up when I invoke `GetUsers()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, Sitecore uses standard .NET Membership provider.

I would suggest to check what a membership provider is configured in your solution.To do that go to:

`web.config -> /configuration/system.web/membership/providers`

You may have a custom override membership provider where you can have a wrong implementation of some required methods.

Just try to use the following static method of the standard **Microsoft Membership provider**:

```
Membership.FindUsersByName(usernameToMatch, pageIndex, pageSize, out totalRecords)
```

Comment: I do - I am, in fact, using the AD Module. I even decompiled their DLL to try to figure out what's going wrong, but to no avail.

Comment: I remember, I had pretty the same issue when I used **Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain.GetUsers()** where `PagingIterator with yield return` was returning wrong amount of users.

Comment: So, how did you got around it?

Comment: I used to another **Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain.GetUsersByName(some params)** method that the same as above but does not use custom iterator:

`MembershipUserCollection usersByName = Membership.FindUsersByName(this.AccountPrefix + search, pageIndex, pageSize, out total);
      List<User> userList = new List<User>();
      foreach (MembershipUser membershipUser in usersByName)
        userList.Add(User.FromName(membershipUser.UserName, false));
      return (IEnumerable<User>) userList;`

Comment: Looping through FindUsersByName did the trick, thanks! Apparently, I am unable to return all the users in one go.

Comment: If you write this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No. Please edit the already given answer. This is not a forum guys, users of this site should not need to read through a "thread" for clues.